# Insert form data in database

Tags: php, database, sql-insert

I have a problem: Every time I insert something in the database, at the end of it a `/` appears. How can I remove this? I think the problem is with `escape_str` in the model. What can I replace it with?

VIEW

```
foreach($ciList as $row)
{
  echo "<p><input type=checkbox name=cname[]  value=".$row->affected_ci."/>".$row->affected_ci."</p>";
}
```

CONTROLLER

```
public function insert()
{
    $this->load->model('some_model');
    $name = $this->input->post('name');
    $cname = $this->input->post('cname');

    foreach($cname as $key=>$value)
    {
      $success = $this->some_model->insertPerson($name,$cname[$key]);
    }

    if($success == TRUE)
      $this->insert_page(TRUE);
    else 
      $this->insert_page(FALSE);
}
```

MODEL

```
public function insertPerson($name,$cname)
{
    $escName = $this->db->escape_str($name);
    $eciName = $this->db->escape_str($cname);
    $queryStr = "INSERT INTO appwarehouse.ci_table(app_id,ci_name) VALUES ('$escName','$eciName')";
    $query = $this->db->query($queryStr);
    return $query;
}
```

Comment: echo variables `$escName` and `$eciName` and check whether they contain `/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
echo "<p><input type=checkbox name=cname[]  value=".$row->affected_ci."/>".$row->affected_ci."</p>";
```

to

```
echo "<p><input type=checkbox name=cname[]  value='".$row->affected_ci."' />".$row->affected_ci."</p>";
```

Comment: It still has the "/" in the insert. i think there is omething wrong with the model

Comment: did you echoed the variables? Check whether the variable itself contains `/`. If not the problem will be with model.

Answer (score 0):

Change to

```
foreach($ciList as $row){
            echo "<p><input type='checkbox' name='cname[]'  value='".$row->affected_ci."'/>".$row->affected_ci."</p>";
            }
```